# Error in Flowbite-react floating label documentation page

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

I wanted to use the floating label component from the `flowbite-react` library. The snippet provided on the page imports `Spinner` from `flowbite-react. Has anyone else come across this issue?

[flowbite-react floating label documentation page](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/forms/floating-label)

```
import { Spinner } from 'flowbite-react';
    
function Component() {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-flow-col justify-stretch space-x-4">
      <FloatingLabel variant="filled" label="Label" />
      <FloatingLabel variant="outlined" label="Label" />
      <FloatingLabel variant="standard" label="Label" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens compared to what you expect to happen? Do you have any error messages you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `FloatingLabel` and use it. This will work.

```
import { FloatingLabel } from 'flowbite-react';
```

Still if not, Install and setup Tailwind CSS to use `flowbite`:

```
npm i autoprefixer postcss tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Add the `flowbite` plugin to `tailwind.config.js`, and include content from `flowbite-react`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    // ...
    'node_modules/flowbite-react/lib/esm/**/*.js',
  ],
  plugins: [
    // ...
    require('flowbite/plugin'),
  ],
};
```

Refer this [docs](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/getting-started/introduction) to correctly setup the `tailwind` and `flowbite-react`. Then it will work.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine for me. Could you please share your output screenshot and the `tailwind.config` file code.

Comment: I installed the dependencies again and it worked for me as well,thanks!